# Xpath also parent child contains spesific value

Tags: c#, xpath

I have a html structure as below

```
 <tr valign="middle" align="left">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="table_row"><div align="left"></div></td>
  <td class="table_row"><div align="right" class="news_headline_txt">&nbsp;</div></td>
  <td class="table_row"><div align="right">28.02.2013</div></td>
  <td class="table_row"><div align="right"><a onClick="window.open('show.php?id=id_9000')" href="javascript:;"></a></div></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I can get onclick value as below

```
"//a[contains(@onclick, 'id_')]/@href
```

but when i get the onclick value, i want match tr's third td values `<td class="table_row"><div align="right">28.02.2013</div></td>`contains **02.03**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find a TR that has a td with a certain position, and then find the anchor within that:

```
//tr[td[position()=4][contains(text(), '02.03')]]//a[contains(@onclick, 'id_')]/@href
```

You could also use the `sibling` axis:

```
//td[position()=4][contains(text(), '02.03')]/following-sibling:td//a[contains(@onclick, 'id_')]/@href
```

Note the position check is for the 4th `td`, since there is a blank padding `td` at the beginning of the row.